# How can I show error message from server side?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I'm using PHP curl to post my data to server side and my front-end is using angularjs. How could I retrieve the `curl_error()` then show to the user?

My PHP

```
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
if ($err) {

    return View::make('dashborad.home');
}
```

My Js

```
if ($scope.form.$valid) {
    // is loading
    $scope.loading = true;
    // prepare data packet
    var data = {};
    angular.forEach($scope.form, function (v, k) {
        if (k.indexOf('$') < 0 && typeof v.$dirty !== 'undefined' && v.$dirty) {
            data[k] = v.$modelValue;
        }
    });
                    // ajax save REST
    return Module.sync(data)
        .then(function (res) {
            $scope.loading = false;
            $scope.message = res.message;
            $scope.success = true;
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.success = false;
            }, 500);
            $scope.form.$setPristine();
            return res;
        }, function (err) {
            // stop loading
            $scope.loading = false;
            $scope.errors = err.errors;
            $.scrollTo(0, 500);
            return err;
        });
}
```

Comment: Did you try replacing `return View::make('dashborad.home')` to `return $err;`?

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez Yes, but it still showing the success.

Comment: Then you need to send the HTTP status code from the server. You could try by sending a custom HTTP response with: `return Response::json(['ErrorMessage' => $err], 500);`. The reject parameter function of promise should be executed because the server is responding with 500 HTTP response status code.